# Is there an Iterator-like function (or workaround) for Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add a sequence of letters as Strings to a 2D array.  So `object [17]` goes to `endState[0][0]`; `[18]` to `endState[0][1]` and so forth.

The problem I have is with the outside for loop, which just adds object at `[32]` to all of the cells in the matrix.  Normally I would use an iterator to deal with this when using other collections, however, it is not possible with arrays as far as i am aware (I am a novice as you may have guessed).

```
String [][] endState = new String[4][4];        
for(int i1=17;i1<33;i1++){          
    for(int r=0;r<endState.length;r++){
        for(int c=0;c<endState.length;c++){
        endState[r][c] = config.split("")[i1];
        }
    }                       
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like that ?

```
String[] configs = config.split("");
String [][] endState = new String[4][4];        
int i = 17;        
for(int r=0;r<endState.length;r++){
    for(int c=0;c<endState.length;c++){
        endState[r][c] = configs[i++];
    }
}
```

Comment: BOOM!  Thank you!

Comment: this is one of the easiest way, however I like @Peter Lawrey first solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn the letters into a gird you can do.

```
String[] letters = config.substring(17).split("");
String[][] endState = new String[4][];
for (int i = 0; i < endState.length; i++)
    endState[i] = Arrays.copyOf(letters, i * 4, 4);
```

or you could do

```
String[][] endState = IntStream.range(0, 4)
                                .mapToObject(i -> Arrays.copyOf(letters, i * 4, 4))
                                .toArray(s -> new String[s][]);
```

Comment: Thank you, @iMysak solution was chosen because it already fit the code block I had without any big change.  I will look at this in my second pass to see if I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8, you can do it as follows:

```
Arrays.asList(someArray).foreach(item -> {});
```

or

```
Arrays.asList(someArray).stream().ANY_STREAM_FUNCTION_HERE
```

If you want iterate your 2dim array:

```
Arrays.asList(someArray).foreach(item -> {
    Arrays.asList(item).foreach(item2 -> {[Do your job here]})
});
```

You can do it more Java 7 way:

```
for(item : Arrays.asList(someArray)) {
    ...
}
```

Anyway you can always use `Arrays.asList(someArray)` to obtain a list from array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not comfortable enough on the functional side yet to go this route although the brevity is nice.

Comment: I added also non functional way (Java 7)

Comment: Thank you, will review this as an alternative on my second pass.  Right now the above solution worked for me.